# Django filter across many to many field

Tags: django

This is a simplified version of my models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Foo(models.Model):
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)

class Bar(models.Mode)
    pass
```

I have a user instance and I would like to compute a queryset for all Bar instances associated with that user. Going from user to Bar consists of getting all Foo objects that have user as owner and then getting all bar instances associated with each Foo.

How can I express this most efficiently using django queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add related names to your model `Foo`. This will facilitate the writing of queries.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    owners = models.ManyToManyField('User', related_name='foo')
    bar = models.ForeignKey('Bar', related_name='foo')
```

Now assuming that you have a single user instance as you mentioned, you could make a query like this:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
qs = Bar.objects.filter(foo__owners=user)
```

If you by most efficient mean the performance and not the expression, then you should take a look at `prefetch_related` and `select_related` methods of QuerySet.